# Use db data on Azure login page

Tags: azure, t-sql

I have site, located on azure. In my data base I have specific flag (lets name it IsRegistered). If this flag is false, then user should be redirected to sign up page, otherwise - to sign in one. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What type of user store are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to show specifically what you're referring to, and where you're stuck. As written though, this is unfortunately off-topic: it's a bit unclear what you're specifically asking, and also very broad (there are lots of ways to handle user authentication and authorization).